# Where exactly compilers store local variables

Tags: compiler-construction

I'm in the process of writing a compiler for an older 8 bit processor (a tiny subset of C), that should generate assembler code (or machine code directly, doesn't matter).

Where should local variables be stored? On the (normal call) stack or some separate data stack? So should at the beginning of a function the space be reserved (maybe initialized) and on the return cleaned up? Note, that interrupts could modify the area below the (call) stack pointer at any time.

Comment: standard doesn't define that. You can do whatever you like. Most compilers are using stack for function local variables. For 8-bit machine you can try do some optimizations based on hardware capability (some hardware have fast ram and slow ram).

Comment: Automatic zeroing/initialization is considered good practice present day, but it used to be considered unnecessary overhead. I certainly remember my share of bugs back in the 90s that depended on which function had been previously called and what it left in a spot that was later reused on the stack for a particular local.

Answer (score 1):

Common practice is to store local variables in processor registers, if possible. (On an 8-bit machine this sometimes isn't an option.) The remaining local variables are typically stored on the normal data stack.

The *entry* code emitted for a function typically does the following:

- Reserve a number of bytes on the stack, by adjusting the stack pointer.
- Store *callee-save* registers, if needed. (I.e. registers that the calling-convention says should not be changes over the function call.)
- Initializes local variables.

The *exit* code typically does the following:

- Restore the *callee-save* registers.
- Unreserve the area on the stack by adjusting the stack pointer in the other direction.

As you noted yourself, a function can never rely on data on the "wrong" side of the stack pointer, as that can be modified by interrupt functions.

Comment: So a typical function starts with a couple of `push`es and ends with a couple of `pop`s?

Comment: Often, yes. Of course, everything depends on the instruction set. If you are lucky you might have a "push multiple" instruction. In some cases the compiler vendor could provide helper subroutines that perform push and pop, to reduce the code size.